# How can I convert JSON to work with CLLocationCoordinate2D in Swift

Tags: json, swift, cllocationcoordinate2d

I used a web service and saved a JSON data into my jsonArray. Now I'm trying to apply the data into CLLocationCoordinate2D like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.jsonArray["JSONResults"][0]["lat"],longitude: self.jsonArray["JSONResults"][0]["long"])
```

Swift Compiler tells me:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' with an argument list of type (latitude: JSON, longitude: JSON)
```

I tried using as Int but it still doesn't work. How can I properly convert this appropriately?

Example of my JSON data:

```
{
"long" : "121.513358",
"tel" : "(02)2331-6960",
"lat" : "25.044976",
"add" : "xxx",
"region" : "yyy",
"name" : "zzz"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the library SwiftyJSON to decode your JSON.

This library creates objects of type `JSON`, you have to extract their value before using it.

Since your values in the response seem to be `String`s and you need `Double`s for `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, this should work:

```
let lat = self.jsonArray["JSONResults"][0]["lat"].stringValue
let long = self.jsonArray["JSONResults"][0]["long"].stringValue
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat)!, longitude: Double(long)!)
```

In this example I'm using the SwiftyJSON non-optional getters `stringValue`. But you can also use the optional getters `.string` if the values could be nil:

```
if let lat = self.jsonArray["JSONResults"][0]["lat"].string, let long = self.jsonArray["JSONResults"][0]["long"].string, let latitude = Double(lat), let longitude = Double(long) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
}
```

Comment: exactly as you described